# Python. Pandas. Merge

Tags: python, pandas

I have written a code that merges File B into File A based on a column 'Code'. Some of the values from File B, however, are generic ('Color') and I would need to do another merge with file C - but instead of creating a new column I would like to use the same column created during the first merge and whenever first merge returned value 'Color' only for those rows do merge with file C to get the proper value.

I went as far as merging A with B:

```
import pandas as pd

File_A = pd.read_excel(r'.../My Files/Python/Supplier cat testing/File A.xlsx')
File_B = pd.read_excel(r'.../My Files/Python/Supplier cat testing/File B.xlsx')
File_C = pd.read_excel(r'.../My Files/Python/Supplier cat testing/File C.xlsx')
results = pd.merge(File_A, File_B[['Code','Color']], on='Code')

results.to_excel('Output_File.xlsx', index=False)
```

Would anyone have any idea where do I even start, please?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: ...which is to say -- you're expected to have already started (and thus encountered a narrow, specific problem) before asking here.

Comment: @TomSelleck Code added.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Point taken. I am pretty new to this page. I have added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
dfOut = dfB.copy()
dfOut['Color'] = dfB.merge(dfC, on='Code').apply(lambda r: r.Color_x if r.Color_y == 'Color' else r.Color_y, axis=1)
print(df)
```

#### Output

```
   Code   Color
0     0   Green
1     1  Yellow
2     2  Orange
3     3     Red
4     4   Black
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. So the code basically creates the output file as a copy of the dfB and then merges it with dfC on Code by replacing values in column 'Color' on the dfB file by performing merge with dfC on 'Code' columns and then with conditional statement used with a lambda whenever the value is 'Color' it uses the proper color from the dfC? Use r.Color_x if r.Color_y == 'Color' otherwise use r.Color_y. What are: r.Color_x and r.Color_y? I can't quite grasp how does that work? Thank you.

Comment: The 'r' refers to row.   After the merge, the 'Color' from dfB and dfC become 'Color_x' and 'Color_y' respectively (there is a way to force the name, e.g. Color_B and Color_C).   So r.Color_x refers to the Color value from dfB.   And r.Color_y refers to dfC.    Now you just do the logic that if one value is 'Color' then use the other.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. Please, but how the 'Color' from dfB and dfC become 'Color_x' and 'Color_y' respectively? This I can't understand. How does Python know Color_x refers to dfB and not dfC - or even why does it refer to anything at all? I really searched for the answer online... And played around with the code, i.e. changed Color_x to Color_a and Color_y to Color_b to see how it will affect the output but it only produced the error "Series' object has no attribute 'Color_b"...

Comment: Look up `merge' function - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: On the merge() function add suffixes = ['_b', '_c'] then you can use r.color_b and r.color_c.

Comment: Thank you! I think I got it. So x and y are assigned by default to the data frame (dfB) and object to merge with (dfC). Makes sense now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225844/discussion-between-adrian-and-frankr6591).

Comment: In the code you have proposed, how do I use it if my column names have spaces in them, e.g. 'Color' is now 'Color Name', so these didn't work for me: "apply(lambda r: r.Color Name_x if r.Color Name_y == 'Color' else r.Color Name_y, axis=1)" or "apply(lambda r: r['Color Name']_x if r[Color Name']_y == 'Color' else r['Color Name']_y, axis=1)" Thank you.

Comment: use "apply(lambda r: r['Color Name_x'] if r[Color Name_y'] == 'Color' else r['Color Name_y'], axis=1)"

Comment: Thank you! I have responded to your question in the chat if you would like to check it out please. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225844/discussion-between-adrian-and-frankr6591